# Model Fluent validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, fluentvalidation

I have a model with list of items and I have an rule for Property OrderQty and it must be an number (i.e. 0-9). If the rule will fail it should return the message with ItemNo from the list of objects .

```
RuleFor(m => new { m.OrderQty, m.ItemNumber }).Must(x => validateint(x.OrderQty, x.ItemNumber)).WithMessage(string.Format(Item {0} Must be an integer",x.ItemNumber));
```

My Items class is like

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OrderQty{ get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

I expected the output should be ErrorMessage as "Item 'Itemnumberhere' must be an integer"

Comment: what is the actual output as of now? and please provide the validateint function code as well. Just the psuedocode is fine.

Comment: As of now i am getting compile time error as The name 'x' does not exist in the current context
 
 And my validateint function is 
 
  public bool validateint(string value,string Item)
        {
            int number;
            bool a = int.TryParse(value, out number);
            return a;
        }
 
 The OrderQty Property is a string so here i am using this function

Comment: Added the answer. Check it out and let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
RuleFor(m => new { m.OrderQty, m.ItemNumber }).Must(x => validateint(x.OrderQty, x.ItemNumber)).WithMessage(x => $"Item {x.ItemNumber} Must be an integer"))

RuleFor(m => new { m.OrderQty, m.ItemNumber }).Must(x => validateint(x.OrderQty, x.ItemNumber)).WithMessage(x => string.Format("Item {0} Must be an integer",x.ItemNumber))

 RuleFor(m => m).NotEmpty().WithMessage(x => { return string.Format("Item {0} Must be an integer", x.ReportName); });
```

you should get the format you need.

Using string.format and $ uses the same functions. Use $ method to make the code more readable. Just a tip

Comment: I also tried this but still i am getting compile time error as like Unexpected character '$' and invalid expression terms "

Comment: you must be using a old version of c# / visual studio i believe. c#5 and above only has the $. try the second one with the string.format

Comment: @Vicky Format strings with `$`is only valid in C# 6 or higher

Comment: @Vicky modified the answer to suit your c# version. check it out.

Comment: Yes i am using C# 5.0 and i tried this x => string.Format("Item {0} Must be an integer",x.ItemNumber) but still getting compile time errors . Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type 
 Delegate 'System.Func<ABC.MODELS.ViewModels.Item,AnonymousType#1,string>' does not take 1 arguments 
 'ABC.MODELS.ViewModels.Item' does not contain a definition for 'ItemNumber' and no extension method 'ItemNumber' accepting a first argument of type 'ABC.MODELS.ViewModels.Item' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Okay.... I will see how to make my version lower since my IDE actually works fine with the code snippet above. Please do modify the question to reflect c# 5 version and .net framework version as well.

Comment: I also suggest if you can, move to visual studio 2015 and above to use c# 6.0, as it will automatically solve your issues once you upgrade.

Comment: @vicky try the third one

Comment: Then how could i validate my string to int here RuleFor(x => x.OrderQty).Must(validateint).WithMessage(m => { return string.Format("Item {0} Must be an integer", m.ItemNumber); });

Comment: RuleFor(x => x.OrderQty).Must(validateint).WithMessage(x => { return string.Format("Item {0} Must be an integer", x.OrderQty); }); Not sure if it will work. But this should be considered as return type string